# How to have modularized details-Template for older version of KendoUI Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, telerik

Ok so some background. We are in Angular/Kendo environment. However, we are using an older version of KendoUI from Q2-2014. What does it mean?

- It means that if we want to use the details template with Kendo-Grid then we can not use the new Angular Directive **k-detail-template**. If we use it then it does not render properly as a Kendo template as it can be seen on this Dojo http://dojo.telerik.com/oMEvI/6. As you can see, if we choose a newer library then details template is supported but the older one is no supported. However, we do not have luxury to update our Kendo library right now so we need to figure out an alternative with the old school library that we have.
- Now, our work around is to use it the way it was used in classic JQuery as seen in Dojo here: http://dojo.telerik.com/otiqU

It works and so far so good. However, it is not modularized in nature and it requires me to include the HTML template inside the Controller which is not the most elegant way to do it(at least in my opinion). My question is How can I have the template below:

```
 detailTemplate: "<b>This is where all the details go</b>",
```

Instead of being assigned inline, come from a separate HTML view so that it does not litter my controller with unwanted html?

Answer (score 2):

Two things come to mind.

```
 detailTemplate: kendo.template($("#myTemplate").html()),
```

Or

```
clientTemplateID="tmpGridViewItem",


<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="tmpGridViewItem">
    <div class="gridViewItem">
        <h3>#:ModelFieldValue#</h3>
    </div>
</script>
```

Or

```
 var templateContent = that._templates.divA;
 var template = kendo.template(templateContent);
 ...

 _templates: {
                divA: "<div style='position:absolute;'> <img src='#=data.imageUrl#' alt='Help' ></img></div>",
                divB: "<div style='position:absolute; ><img class='k-button' src='#=data.imageUrl#' alt='Help' ></img></div>"
            }
```

Comment: I think that your solutions are doing a separate DIV in the same file where you can do a simple $(#'') JQUery call. However, what I want to be able to do is to be able load it from a completely different Html file. Is that Do-able?

Comment: I am sure it can be. Once inside of the dom and you have knowledge of how to bind then you should be able to use templates in scope, even when originally defined in separate html.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What worked for me though is detailsTemplate : $("#myTemplate").html() where $("#myTemplate').html() is simply a div. For some mysterious reasons Angular did not work with kendo.template